# Search List Item SharePoint 2010

Tags: list, search

I am trying to search some pages from "Site Pages" Library. 
Here is my sample code

```
string q= @"<Where>
                        <Eq>
                           <FieldRef Name='Name' Ascending='False' />
                           <Value Type='Text'>Home</Value>
                        </Eq>
                     </Where>";
  SPQuery query = new SPQuery { Query = q, RowLimit = 1 };      
  SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
```

On executing the above code I get the following error.

"One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast I resolved the problem by using internal name for the column "Name" as "FileLeafRef".

Thanks all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

I think that 'Name' is just the *display* name for the field you want to query. You probably need to use the *internal* name for the field, which is probably something like 'LinkFileName' or 'Title'

Comment: How can i find the internal name?

Comment: With powershell/Microsoft SharePoint Snap-In: $w = get-spweb <webUrl>; $l = $w.Lists["yourlist"]; $f = $l.Fields.GetField("Name"); $f.InternalName. This will give "FileLeafRef".

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to reference the "Name" field in the ViewFields of the SPQuery object:

```
query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Name' />";
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but this doesn't work. What I see is there are other columns named as "Name" for "Site Pages" Library.This could be the problem may be.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into the list settings for the list you are trying to query, and hover over the column (in this case 'Name'), you should be able to see the field type for that column.

For example, for the Name column in a SharePoint list, you might see the following:

```
https://yoursharepointsite/_layouts/FldEdit.aspx?List=%7B80CABC04%2D5AB5%2D4595%2DA265%2DDC50272F8BA8%7D&Field=Title
```

So you'd use

```
<FieldRef Name='Title'>
```

in your query for that list.

Comment: For some reason "Name" column is not listed in the list of columns for "Site Pages"